# Carrying a concealed filet knife in Colorado

Tags: criminal-law, colorado

Webpages like [Colorado Knife Law](https://knifeup.com/colorado-knife-law/) and others list Colorado law pertaining to concealed knives as such:

> These knives are illegal to carry concealed:

> All knives less than 3.5 inches are legal.

> All fishing and hunting knives of any length are legal.

> All knives over 3.5 inches are illegal.

So, can I carry a concealed 6 inch filet knife in Colorado?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Colorado Revised Statutes,  [18-12-101](http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/colorado?source=COLO;CODE&tocpath=1G8HF3QKZC9YJ08IV,2IKCPJHQMOM5AHP0K,3JG1IKVXA6O0OU7DJ;1UQNO57TCEU384AN2,2S0KIZO520NMQHQ17,3F4HK0NG03MAZUMCT;18M2FKK04GEHPK710,2HKWCJ1RR8QY9BI43,3NUEOST9PASC58FLL;10N3ETSGF1G42LYVT,28S5M05C01JZ5BS6I,3BCPMPP4QKK9DMZ3E&shortheader=no) and [105](http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/colorado?source=COLO;CODE&tocpath=1G8HF3QKZC9YJ08IV,2IKCPJHQMOM5AHP0K,3JG1IKVXA6O0OU7DJ;1UQNO57TCEU384AN2,2S0KIZO520NMQHQ17,3F4HK0NG03MAZUMCT;18M2FKK04GEHPK710,2HKWCJ1RR8QY9BI43,3NUEOST9PASC58FLL;1VKU7EXSK4WSSMI76,28JIM8GU7XFMNU4GV,33MH4OPZXJV03HYXW&shortheader=no). It's a fishing knife. But you might get a ticket or even arrested. The fact that it's a fishing knife is an affirmative defense.

Edit to add: relevant podcast - http://www.lifeofthelaw.org/2015/06/opinel-no-5/ (story about a guy who gets arrested carrying an Opinel no. 12 in TN)

Comment: It might be useful if you quote some relevant parts of the podcast, in case that link breaks.

Comment: The statutory definition of knife "does not include a hunting or fishing knife carried **for sports use**".  If you're carrying a 6 inch filet knife in your overcoat pocket at 3am in downtown Denver, it will be pretty hard to argue that it's "for sports use".